# Java: Dynamic variables response as JSON

Tags: java, json

Suppose there is a code that get multiple dates variable as:

```
Date dateVar1 = Date1;
Date dateVar2 = Date2;
Date dateVar3 = Date3;
```

I can return these dates as `JSON` as below:

```
response.setContentType("application/json");
response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
response.getWriter().write("dateVar1 =" + dateVar1 + "dateVar2 =" + dateVar2 + "dateVar3 =" + dateVar3);
```

But this won't work with large or dynamic number of variables, so my question is how to return JSON response in this case?

Comment: You are in Java, you can use JSONObject to create a JSON file, you then just have to loop on your data adding new params to your JSONObject before sending it.

Comment: @xoxel never dealt with JsonObject before, would you please submit it as an answer?

Comment: Well nevermind, Danila's solution seems like a good one to your problem :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use jackson ObjectMapper to convert object to JSON and vice versa.

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
String  jsonString = mapper.writeValueAsString(yourObject);
response.setContentType("application/json");
response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
response.getWriter().write(jsonString);
```

Comment: How the ObjectMapper will deal with dynamic variables in this case?

Comment: it will convert all fields in your object to JSON representation. No difference 3 fields or 33 fields.